# R: When relabelling my X and Y Axis the new names overlap the old

Tags: r, scatter-plot, axis-labels

I used this code to make a scatter plot and to give it a heading, as well as relabel the axes:

```
#Create scatter plot number 1
#x = Written Frequency, y = RTlexdec
plot(dataset$WrittenFrequency, dataset$RTlexdec)
#Call title() function to label axes and give a title
title(main = "Scatter plot 1: WrittenFrequency & RTlexdec ", sub = NULL, xlab = "Y: WrittenFrequency", ylab = "X: RTlexdec")
```

However the output isn't the new axes labels alone, they are written over the top of the ones R generated. How can I fix this?

Comment: You could add `xlab = NA, ylab = NA` to the first `plot` statement

Answer (score 0):

You can print the desired title and labels in `plot()`, rather than splitting them up:

```
plot(df, main = "Scatter plot 1: WrittenFrequency & RTlexdec ", xlab = "Y: WrittenFrequency", ylab = "X: RTlexdec")
```

Alternatively, if you wish to split it up, you can specify xlab and ylab as NA:

```
plot(df, xlab=NA, ylab=NA)
title(main = "Scatter plot 1: WrittenFrequency & RTlexdec ", sub = NULL, xlab = "Y: WrittenFrequency", ylab = "X: RTlexdec")
```